# Fire event from another event with different args

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to fire event from one event the another.

```
private void ugTopActivity_FillSceneGraph(object sender, FillSceneGraphEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Something();
        }

private void ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(object sender, ChartDataEventArgs e)
            {
               //I need to fire FillSceneGraph event from here.
               ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(sender,e) // This doesn't work because 'e' Types are not convertable
            }
```

How can i call from event to another with different eventargs type ?

Answer (score 2):

I will enhance the answer of [@Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079221/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani), as he said, you need to create a new `FillSceneGraphEventArgs` object and send to `ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked`.

```
private void ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(object sender, ChartDataEventArgs e)
{
    //I need to fire FillSceneGraph event from here.
    var ev = new FillSceneGraphEventArgs(scene, core); // SceneGraph and ChartCore

    ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(sender, ev);
}
```

**NOTE**

1. This may crash or work in the unexpected way because you fired the event yourself. So make sure you get appropriate or circumstantial `SceneGraph` and `ChartCore`
2. Take care of the **sender** also, `ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked` may request a specific sender **object type**

Comment: thank you, however how should i define scene and core

Comment: To answer I need to see your code, you may take a look at the documentation - http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2016.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinChart.v16.1~Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Events.FillSceneGraphEventHandler.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use `null` if you don't use `e` in `ugTopActivity_FillSceneGraph`:

```
ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(sender, null);
```

Otherwise, you can create the event args yourself like:

```
FillSceneGraphEventArgs event = new FillSceneGraphEventArgs(parameters here); //I'm not familiar with this event so don't know its arguments
    ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked(sender, event);
```

Comment: its not null. however didn't understand your answer. FillSceneGraphEventArgs parameters are  (object sender, FillSceneGraphEventArgs e)

Comment: @johntrue ignore the first part of the answer and go to the second part. you need `FillSceneGraphEventArgs` as an argument to pass in to `ugTopActivity_ChartDataClicked`. So you should create one and pass it to the method.

Comment: still don't get it. could you please re-write full code ?